# Is there any way to speed up the execution time of the X13 Arima Analysis?

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, arima

I'm currently using the X13_arima_analysis function of statsmodels in Python: [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.x13.x13_arima_analysis.html). It is pretty slow. I understand that it's reaching out to a binary that was created by the US Census, and having the binary process the time series, but is there any alternative to making it faster? I've actually also tested in R as well using the seas package and it was basically double the execution time of the Python code.

(The alternative could be in other languages as well. Not restricting the solution to Python)

I tried both Python (statsmodels) and R (seas). Python was ~24 secs and R was ~49 secs with the same size data.

Comment: Given the durations you list, I'm guessing you have a lot of data. Writing it to a file and reading it might be a little expensive, but the processing itself will be about as fast as it can be. Creating a subprocess is not a major part of your overhead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to speed up the execution time of performing the x13_arima_analysis. @MadPhysicist is correct, it is a lot of data. It is time series data for multiple countries, spanning back to ~1990. I've identified the x13_arima process as the bottleneck of the code. If there is no way to speed that part up, I get it. I'm just wondering if I may have missed something to solve the long execution time.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I actually think that the x13_arima_analysis function writes the data to a file behind the scenes, and sends that data to the binary the Census created.

Comment: @Algoriithmm. Yeah, you're hobbled by disk I/O and quantity of data. Your only reasonable path forward is to get your hands on the census source code, or the paper that explains what it does, and re-implement it on your own if it's not patented or something.

Comment: I figured as much. Thanks for the input.